# In app purchase issue when buying product

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I'm doing in a In app purchase, after clicking the button 
(multiple times it showed login alert of my test user)

```
- (IBAction)BuyProduct:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}
```

then code moves to

```
case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

Finally my console shows:

```
2013-12-06 18:56:13.694 sample_purchase[505:60b] Transaction Failed
2013-12-06 18:56:20.553 sample_purchase[505:60b] <SKPaymentQueue: 0x166809c0>: Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: because already restoring transactions
2013-12-06 18:56:21.844 sample_purchase[505:60b] <SKPaymentQueue: 0x166809c0>: Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: because already restoring transactions
```

Please help!

Comment: i am not sure but i think this problem with **NSNotificationCenter** that multiple time registered it's same Observation. so please remove Observation after that used.

Comment: I haven't add any word NSNotificationCenter on my code ! just NSUserDefault to save the purchase.

Comment: @remus Yes! The login alert view pops up often due to unfinished transaction left previously. Forgot to add finish transaction code.

Answer (score 1):

This may useful to you:

```
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {

    if ([[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions] count]) {

        NSLog(@"We get very non-patient user");

        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions])
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }else{

         [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
    }
}
```